# Need help opening filled InfoPath forms stored in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, office-365, office

I have an InfoPath form library in O365.  My users can submit browser forms, but I can't open the forms to view them.  I've tried opening them in the browser and downloading them.  When I download them and try to open them in InfoPath Designer or Filler, I get a message that the template is needed.  Does anyone know how to open one of these forms?
Thanks